# How can I troubleshoot Customization.InvalidCstDocumentXML during minor Acumatica version upgrade?

Tags: acumatica

This is more of a nuisance than a blocking problem as we can upgrade by unpublishing the customization project to perform the upgrade (recommended anyway) and then republishing it after the upgrade is complete.  However, this problem is relatively new to me.

What steps if any can I take to troubleshoot my customization project that prevents upgrading from 19.205.0023 to 19.207.0026?  There are no errors in publishing before or after the upgrade, but I get the following error during the upgrade.

```
Customization.InvalidCstDocumentXML: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ---> Customization.InvalidCstDocumentXML: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Customization.CstDocContainer.LoadChildItems(XmlElement parent) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Web.Customization\CstDocumentDOM\CstDocument.cs:line 1025
at Customization.CstDocContainer..ctor(XmlElement item) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Web.Customization\CstDocumentDOM\CstDocument.cs:line 1017
at Customization.CstAUPropsContainer..ctor(XmlElement item) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Web.Customization\CstDocumentDOM\CstAUScreenField.cs:line 21
at Customization.CstDocument.CreatePersistObject(Type type, XmlElement xmlElement) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Web.Customization\CstDocumentDOM\CstDocument.cs:line 775
at Customization.CstDocument.CreatePersistObject[T](XmlElement xmlElement) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Web.Customization\CstDocumentDOM\CstDocument.cs:line 756
at Customization.CstDocument.PersistObjectFromXml(XmlElement item) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Web.Customization\CstDocumentDOM\CstDocument.cs:line 826
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Customization.CstDocument.PersistObjectFromXml(XmlElement item) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Web.Customization\CstDocumentDOM\CstDocument.cs:line 832
at Customization.CstDocContainer.LoadChildItems(XmlElement parent) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Web.Customization\CstDocumentDOM\CstDocument.cs:line 1022
at Customization.CstDocContainer..ctor(XmlElement item) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Web.Customization\CstDocumentDOM\CstDocument.cs:line 1017
at Customization.CstAutomationContainer..ctor(XmlElement item) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Web.Customization\CstDocumentDOM\CstWorkflowContainer.cs:line 25
at Customization.CstDocument.CreatePersistObject(Type type, XmlElement xmlElement) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Web.Customization\CstDocumentDOM\CstDocument.cs:line 775
at Customization.CstDocument.CreatePersistObject[T](XmlElement xmlElement) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Web.Customization\CstDocumentDOM\CstDocument.cs:line 756
at Customization.CstDocument.PersistObjectFromXml(XmlElement item) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Web.Customization\CstDocumentDOM\CstDocument.cs:line 822
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Customization.CstDocument.PersistObjectFromXml(XmlElement item) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Web.Customization\CstDocumentDOM\CstDocument.cs:line 832
at Customization.CstDocument.LoadXml(XmlDocument doc) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Web.Customization\CstDocumentDOM\CstDocument.cs:line 399
at Customization.CstDocument.LoadXml(String xml) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Web.Customization\CstDocumentDOM\CstDocument.cs:line 354
at Customization.CstDocument.LoadPackage(Stream stream) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Web.Customization\CstDocumentDOM\CstDocument.cs:line 929
at PX.Web.Customization.utils.PublishOffline.ValidateCustomization(String srcWebsite) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Web.Customization\utils\PublishOffline.cs:line 279
at PX.Web.Customization.utils.PublishOffline.Invoke(String[] args) in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2019R214-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Web.Customization\utils\PublishOffline.cs:line 404
```

As I read this, it seems to complain about Customization.InvalidCstDocumentXML.  I don't see anything that actually points to my own code or screen customizations.  All of my code resides in an extension library represented in the project as a DLL file which compiles ok and applies properly to my project.

Are there any steps that I could take to get more detailed information to pinpoint the exact cause of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to avoid this right now. The upgrade process does not guarantee that your published extensions will be loaded and can cause errors like these.

Some customizations, specially the ones done inside Acumatica may work during the upgrade with no issues, but it is common to get some kind of exception for customizations with an external DLL.

The upgrade process recommendation is basically to avoid getting and error and then going back and having to unpublish anyway. It's better to always unpublish your customization first, then perform the upgrade and finally republish again.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  We got in the habit of unpublishing first and then republishing, but once in a while our sysadmin misses the step when upgrading.  Only recently became an issue, so I was hoping to understand what change (on my part or on the Acumatica end) to create the issue.  Definitely not worth the cost to trace it down unless someone happened to be familiar with it already.

Comment: Indeed. Unpublishing all customizations is part of our upgrade process as well.